# is there any restriction on specifying new theme name?

Tags: magento2.2

Is there any restriction on specifying theme name? theme name should always be in lowercase or we can give as per our choice in magento 2?

Comment: Please go through this document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: yup magento suggests to follow standard naming convention i.e. in lowercase. Was just curious to know the impact if it's not written in lowercase though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new theme please follow what Magento core is doing.

Though around 6 months ago, I have created a theme with it's name in uppercase and I have not faced any issue so far.